# Message pop up window at client side

Tags: javascript, popup, c#-2.0

I want code of popup window as message appears when new mail come in yahoo and alert comes on right side i want such a popup in my application can any body suggest me how can i add such popups in my code and from where i will get them. My application is in c#.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write validation for all the textfield.
Like email text box you can check the .,@ because thesae sign must be in email address.and for phone no only digits are required.
And when the function return false you can use Massagebox.show().